# I have the same ID for three different xPath, i can only use one of them, the others doesn't work. (Selenium + Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

#IMPORTS

```
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
import subprocess, sys
def install(package):
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
    install("selenium")
    install("chromedriver_autoinstaller")

#Imports
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get("https://auth.idwall.co/v2")

navegador.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div/button').click()
    
navegador.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="__next"]/form/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/input').send_keys(codigo1)
    
navegador.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="__next"]/form/div/div/button').click()

[enter image description here][1]
```

Only the firs line works, the rest doesn't, how can i get it to work? please, explain very detailed, i am a newbie.

```
**The error i encounter is:** selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="__next"]/form/div/div/button"}
```

i don't think you guys are going to be able to enter the part i am currently stuck cause its going to need the credencials.
Thanksss.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i7BA.png

Comment: The error is quite clear, the element for the specific location doesn't exist. I don't think there is much we can help with, without the webpage and element you are trying to capture?

Comment: Try locating it with `WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='pin']")))`. You need the following imports as well `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By \\\
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait \\\
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC. `Failing that, post your full code, including imports. Also post the URL you are trying to interact with.

Comment: @CeliusStingher i added a picture

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you find the element by its class name. Kindly try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

And then:

```
navegador.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"NumberInput_pinInput__qUJlu").send_keys(codigo1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a clear Xpath for all the elements you want to access.
Try this script:

```
driver.get("https://auth.idwall.co/v2")
WebDriverWait(driver,timeout=10).until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value="//input[@id='user-email']")))
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value="//input[@id='user-email']").click() #optional step
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input[@id='user-email']").send_keys("your_username")
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value="//input[@id='user-password']").click() #optional step
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input[@id='user-password']").send_keys("your_password")
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[text()='Entrar']").click()
```

Note: The script is in English and Selenium 4. You can make use of the locators though and write it in your own format.